# PHP-OOP How can I pass an anchor tag inside the <p> tag?

Tags: php, wordpress, add-filter

[With this WordPress related PHP-OOP Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4082845/1743124), I found my solution for what I's seeking. But with the same function `my_excerpt();` I want to pass another anchor tag (`<a>`) inside the `<p>` tag.

Right now, calling `my_excerpt()` is embracing the db texts with a paragraph tag (`<p>here comes the excerpt</p>`). And if I add my anchor tag like the following:

```
// Echoes out the excerpt
    public static function output() {
        the_excerpt(); ?>
        <a class="read-more" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php _e( 'Read More &raquo;', 'my-theme'); ?></a>
    <?php
    }
```

it's showing the "Read More" just the bottom of the except texts. Inspect Element shows like the following:

```
<p>here comes the excerpt.</p>
<a href="post-link">Read More</a>
```

How can I make changes to the function or class so that I can have the "Read More" link inside the paragraph, like:

```
<p>here comes the excerpt.<a href="post-link">Read More</a></p>
```

#### Additionally

Additionally I'm also trying to remove the `[...]` part from the excerpt generating by the `my_excerpt();`. So I tried the following:

```
function change_excerpt($content) {
    $content = str_replace( '[...]','>',$content ); // remove [...], replace with ...
    $content = strip_tags( $content ); // remove HTML
    return $content;
}
add_filter('my_excerpt','change_excerpt');
```

I doesn't do anything to the view. But if I change it to:

```
add_filter('the_excerpt','change_excerpt');
```

Then unaware, I get the previously desired anchor tag [inside paragraph], because the filter removed the paragraph tag completely.

```
here comes the excerpt.<a href="post-link">Read More</a>
```

But it doesn't do anything with `[...]` portion. :(

So, my furnished Question is:
**How can I put the anchor tag inside the paragraph tag, or remove the paragraph tag, and remove the `[...]` part from the `my_excerpt()` function?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this snippet

Include in your functions.php

```
function kc_excerpt( $length_callback = '', $more_callback = '' ) {

    if ( function_exists( $length_callback ) )
        add_filter( 'excerpt_length', $length_callback );

    if ( function_exists( $more_callback ) )
        add_filter( 'excerpt_more', $more_callback );

    $output = get_the_excerpt();
    $output = apply_filters( 'wptexturize', $output );
    $output = apply_filters( 'convert_chars', $output );
    $output = '<p>' . $output . '</p>';
    echo $output;
}

function kc_excerpt_more( $more ) {
    return '<a class="read-more" href="'. get_permalink() .'" title="'. get_the_title() .'"      rel="bookmark">Read More</a>';
}

function kc_excerpt_more_2($more) {
    return '...';
}

function kc_exdefault($length) {
    return 10;
}

function kc_ex100($length) {
    return 100;
}
```

And call this function from your template file

```
<?php kc_excerpt('kc_exdefault', 'kc_excerpt_more'); ?>
```

or

```
<?php kc_excerpt('kc_ex100', 'kc_excerpt_more_2'); ?>
```