# Display longer excerpt if post does not have a featured image (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been googling this with no result.

I have a bunch of posts. But all of them does not have a featured image. So I was thinking it would look much nicer if all posts still had the same height.

Is it possible to display a longer excerpt if there is no featured image in the post?

Okey so this is what the code looks like now:

```
 /**
 * Set the post excerpt length to 40 words.
 * @param int $length The number of excerpt characters.
 * @return int The filtered number of characters.
 */

function twentyeleven_excerpt_length( $length ) {
return 40;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'twentyeleven_excerpt_length' );
```

Maybe some sort of if statement could do the trick? You know:

```
if (featuredimage = true) {
function twentyeleven_excerpt_length( $length ) {
return 40;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'twentyeleven_excerpt_length' );
}
else {function twentyeleven_excerpt_length( $length ) {
return 80;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'twentyeleven_excerpt_length' );}
```

As you can see I am a total newbie at this so I need some guidance.

Comment: Are you asking if there's an existing option in Wordpress to do this, or are you wanting to program something to do it?

Comment: Questions must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself.

Comment: please edit the question (or create a pastebin) with the content of the PHP that you can find in the php file of your theme that is responsible for the homepage

Comment: @Pikk No, don't make a Pastebin, but put the code in the question: if the Pastebin vanishes, the question gets useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put solution together by

1. Creating a [custom excerpt function to make longer excerpts as shown in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082662/multiple-excerpt-lengths-in-wordpress) and saving it in your functions file
2. Using [has_post_thumbnail](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_post_thumbnail) to see if the post has a thumbnail/featured image, then serve up the correct excerpt accordingly:

   ```
   <?php
   if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
   the_post_thumbnail();
       echo excerpt(25); // Short excerpt
   } else {
       echo excerpt(50); // Long excerpt
   }
   ?>
   ```

Bear in mind that excerpts are trimmed according to word length; therefore you can't guarantee the end height. You should probably also look at using `min-height`  in order to get the height you're after.

Comment: Thank you I'll see what I can do with this.. The height doesn't have to be perfect so increasing the excerpt with some more words would look great.

Comment: Thank you so much. I added the code below just under the original excerpt in funcions.php. Works like a charm!

function my_excerpt_length($length) {

if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
    return 40;
    }
 else {
    return 80;
    }
}
add_filter('excerpt_length', 'my_excerpt_length');

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Advanced Excerpt](http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-excerpt/) plugin.  Use the `has_post_thumbnail()` conditional to test for whether the post has a featured image - if it does, display it + short excerpt (see usage guide for the plugin, you can limit by word count, character count, finish words/sentences and so forth), if it doesn't, display a longer excerpt.  You just use `the_advanced_excerpt()` template tag and pass in the desired parameters.