# Multiple Wordpress excerpt lengths on single page

Tags: wordpress

I've looked through the other solutions for having multiple excerpt lengths in Wordpress, but none of those solutions have worked for me. I need to have two different lengths of excerpt displaying on the same page. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this question and answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19861503/display-longer-excerpt-if-post-does-not-have-a-featured-image-wordpress/19861699#19861699) There's a function that let's you specify how the length of the excerpt on an ad-hoc basis.

Comment: Following your link, I took a second look at the solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082662/multiple-excerpt-lengths-in-wordpress. I guess I was tired last night because I realized this morning that the string I'd been feeding the function (the_excerpt()) was shorter than my limit of 22 words, so of course I wouldn't see my desired number. SMH! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Create your own excerpt. When editing a post or page, click on "Screen options" in the right upper corner, check an excerpt field and write desired content.

Answer (score 0):

I use this plugin:
http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-excerpt/

This allows you to do various things including what you want e.g. from the docs:

```
the_advanced_excerpt('length=320&use_words=0&no_custom=1&ellipsis=%26hellip;&exclude_tags=img,p,strong');
```