# WordPress excerpt height limit

Tags: wordpress, post, height

I want to make in my style for WP excerpt like

[HERE](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/)

When post title is higher, excerpt is reduced to smaller.
Its a plugin or something else?

Comment: You can count title length and adopt this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082662/multiple-excerpt-lengths-in-wordpress

Comment: This is for word limit, i need excerpt height limit. For example max height of excerpt is 100px but excerpt need 150px. On the end of the line at 100px after last word add "..."

Comment: height will be in browser, on server site you can just estimate based on... characters count.

Comment: sure we can write in polish, but it against policy here. You can contact using contacts from my web site.

Comment: Ok sory, im newbie here...

Comment: You have message from me on Facebook. Check your "others" messages.

Comment: for using JQuery on browser side see this: http://blog.johnavis.com/blog/default.asp?id=589

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it with CSS:

```
.truncated_exercept{
overflow:hidden;
text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

but in more then one line in current CSS is not possible with nice … (...) ending, have to use one of js or js+jQuery solutions look there:
http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/

Answer (score 1):

I just found a solution to limiting the number of words in the excerpt without plugins. Add the following code to your functions.php file.

```
<?php
// Custom Excerpt 
function excerpt($limit) {
$excerpt = explode(' ', get_the_excerpt(), $limit);
if (count($excerpt)>=$limit) {
array_pop($excerpt);
$excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt).'...';
} else {
$excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt);
} 
$excerpt = preg_replace('`\[[^\]]*\]`','',$excerpt);
return $excerpt;
}

// Content Limit 
function content($limit) {
$content = explode(' ', get_the_content(), $limit);
if (count($content)>=$limit) {
array_pop($content);
$content = implode(" ",$content).'...';
} else {
$content = implode(" ",$content);
} 
$content = preg_replace('/\[.+\]/','', $content);
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content); 
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
return $content;
}
?>
```

If you want to limit your excerpt to 25 words the code would look like this:

```
<?php echo excerpt(25); ?>
<?php echo content(25); ?>
```

Another way to display limited excerpt by character. Here is the functions.php file code.

```
<?php
function get_excerpt(){
$excerpt = get_the_content();
$excerpt = preg_replace(" (\[.*?\])",'',$excerpt);
$excerpt = strip_shortcodes($excerpt);
$excerpt = strip_tags($excerpt);
$excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, 100);
$excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, strripos($excerpt, " "));
$excerpt = trim(preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', $excerpt));
$excerpt = $excerpt.'... <a href="'.get_the_permalink().'">Read More</a>';
return $excerpt;
}
?>
```

After this you need to add where you want to display your customized character by character.

```
<?php echo get_excerpt(); ?>
```

Source: [Web Design Company Bangladesh](http://www.e2soft.com/blog/custom-excerpt-content-limit-wordpress/)